# Spark dataset related

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

My data set is looking like this by  following code

```
+------+---------------+----+
|  City|      Timestamp|Sale|
+------+---------------+----+
|City 3|6/30/2017 16:04|  28|
|City 4| 7/4/2017 16:04|  12|
|City 2|7/13/2017 16:04|   8|
|City 4|7/16/2017 16:04|  21|
|City 4| 7/3/2017 16:04|  24|
|City 2|7/17/2017 16:04|  34|
|City 3| 7/9/2017 16:04|  13|
|City 3|7/18/2017 16:04|  26|
|City 3| 7/6/2017 16:04|  16|
|City 3|7/15/2017 16:04|  29|
|City 4|7/18/2017 16:04|  39|
|City 2| 7/1/2017 16:04|  19|
|City 2|7/18/2017 16:04|  19|
|City 4| 7/4/2017 16:04|  24|
|City 2| 7/4/2017 16:04|   9|
|City 4|7/15/2017 16:04|  20|
|City 3|7/12/2017 16:04|  19|
|City 1| 7/9/2017 16:04|  13|
|City 1|7/13/2017 16:04|  25|
|City 4|7/10/2017 16:04|  10|
+------+---------------+----+
```

We need to calculate the sum of `Sale` of each `City` in week base.

Comment: provide solution in spark scala

Answer (score 0):

You can group by `City` and `Time stamp` and sum the `Sales`

```
data.groupBy("City", "TimeStamp").agg(sum(col("Sale")).as("TotalSale")).show
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi,it working fine BUT i need week wise ie. week wise sum of sale of each city

Comment: hi ,it working fine but i need week wise sum ie for each week i need sum of sale in each city   [city1 Fri 01/06/2017 38]

Comment: How could some one determine weeks from your given input ?

Comment: did you get how to determine weeks ?